# How to access unbounded Item in DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I'm using a `DataList`. The `ItemTemplate` is bounded. I add a `HeaderTemplate`, and put it inside a table, which will be needed to contain dynamic lables which I add in each FormLoad. I don't want the header to be bounded.

I'm trying to access this table , but it shows me that this table doesn't exist or can't be accessible.

```
if (this.TableCategories.Rows.Count == 0 || 
    this.TableCategories.Rows[this.TableCategories.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Count == 5)
{
    TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
    this.TableCategories.Rows.Add(newRow);
}


<asp:DataList ID="DataListProducts" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
  OnItemCommand="DataListProducts_ItemCommand" Height="200px" Width="100%" 
  BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
  CellPadding="0" GridLines="Vertical" RepeatColumns="6">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="TableCategories" runat="server" BorderColor="Black"  
          CssClass="floatRight" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px" GridLines="Both">
        </asp:Table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataList encapsulates all of its controls. They are not know at page level.

Assuming all controls will always be there, you may try :

```
var myTable = (Table)DataListProducts
             .Controls[0]
             .FindControl("TableCategories");
```